The Temple was made in great part of stone. In what way was it destroyed by fire?
In Nachem we say

כי אתה ה' באש הצתה ובאש אתה עתיד לבנותה.
"For You, O L-rd, set it aflame with fire, and with fire, You will
rebuild it in the future."

I have seen pictures that seem to show the whole structure burning see e.g. Hidabroot or here .
But I see here

Q: I've read about many castles that have been destroyed in fires...
how does this happen? Stone doesn't burn?
A: The non-stone elements of the castle burn, and the stone and mortar
expand and crack in the heat, causing the structure to become
unstable.

Which is correct? (1) The Temple was destroyed entirely by fire
or (2) the non-stone elements of the Temple burned, and the stone expanded and cracked in the heat, causing the structure to become unstable.

(2) https://castletourist.com/can-castles-burn-down/

Always had this question! It’s also interesting to note those midrashim that say that the Temple “sunk into the ground” so according to those it seems it didn’t burn

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5182628/jewish/How-Did-Holy-Temples-of-Stone-Burn.htm

Limestone is even less flamable as compared to other types.

There are some petroleum based compounds which could burn and Romans could use them. This one is medieval but something similar could have been used https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_fire
